# How to make action to a button inside tooltip in Highcharts?

Tags: jquery, svg, highcharts

I've added button inside tooltip in Highcharts and I would like to have some action after click event.

```
config = {
    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
            return "<a href=\"#\" id=\"button\">asd</a>";
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, jQuery doesn't seem to work here well

```
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("ok");
});
```

After click nothing happen. What's wrong? I suppose that the problem is SVG, isn't it?

Comment: It looks like in source code there is a couple of `preventDefault()/stopPropagation()` methods called, when clicking on a container. I would try to use `mousedown` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/tosx33ae/10/

Comment: @PawełFus Unfortunately, I can't use mousedown. I was going to put there about 5 buttons so one wouldn't be able to select other button than the first.

Comment: Then you may need to overwrite methods which are preventing this or edit source code.